# EOSjs getTableRows lower and upper bound on account name

Tags: table, account-name, eosjs

How can I pass an account name as the lower and upper bound in the getTableRows method?

I've looked at types.hpp and saw the string_to_name method, is there a similar method in EOSjs?

Comment: Maybe you should clearify what you are trying to achieve so others get it better and the question is more useful when searched.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The eosjs library has a **format module** that will transform account name strings into the appropriate table keys...

```
const Eos = require("eosjs")
const BigNumber = require("bignumber.js")

const accountName = 'myaccount'
const encodedName = new 
BigNumber(Eos.modules.format.encodeName(accountName, false))
```

** **Notes:**

- Be sure to pass `false` to `format.encodeName`, otherwise, you'll be transforming account names using `littleEndian=true`
- You'll want to use the BigNumber JS library, otherwise, any arithmetic is likely to be incorrect.

Then, you can call `getTableRows` like so...

```
Eos.Localnet({}).getTableRows({
  code: contractName.toString(),
  json: json,
  limit: limit,
  lower_bound: encodedName.toString(),
  scope: contractName.toString(),
  table: tableName.toString(),
  upper_bound: encodedName.plus(1).toString()
})
```

Comment: Unfortunately, there's no `Eos.modules.format.encodeName` in eosjs 20.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example using eosjs@20

```
const BigNumber = require('bignumber.js')
const { Serialize, Numeric } = require('eosjs')
const { TextEncoder, TextDecoder } = require('util')

const numericFromName = (accountName) => {
    const sb = new Serialize.SerialBuffer({
      textEncoder: new TextEncoder(),
      textDecoder: new TextDecoder()
    })

    sb.pushName(accountName)

    return Numeric.binaryToDecimal(sb.getUint8Array(8));
}

const checkUserExists = async ({ blockchain, accountName }) => {
  const numericAccountName = numericFromName(accountName)

  const { rows } = await blockchain.rpc.get_table_rows({
    code: 'accounts',
    scope: 'accounts',
    table: 'users',
    json: true,
    lower_bound: numericAccountName,
    upper_bound: BigNumber(numericAccountName).plus(1)
  })

  return rows.length > 0
}

module.exports = checkUserExists
```